# How to save video?

Tags: android

How to save the video from my raw folder to sd card android, I use this code but the video in the store screen is black and cannot be played

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean success = false;

    // make the directory
    File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "MY VIDEO");
    vidDir.mkdirs();
    // create unique identifier
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    // create file name
    String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
    File fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

    try {
        fileVideo.createNewFile();
        success = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "I use this code but the video in the store screen is black" -- well, among other things, you have not written anything to the file. `createNewFile()` just creates a zero-byte file. Use `openRawResource()` on a `Resources` object to get an `InputStream` on your raw resource, open a `FileOutputStream` on your file, and use Java I/O to copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: How it is? createNewFile() just creates a zero-byte file. Use openRawResource() on a Resources object to get an InputStream on your raw resource, open a FileOutputStream on your file, and use Java I/O to copy the bytes from the InputStream to the FileOutputStream